# How do I modify the h2 database in-built on JBoss AS 7.1?

Tags: jdbc, jboss, h2

I have some information stored in the h2 database which JBoss 7.1 ships with (the one which can be activated by modifying the standalone.xml file in JBoss config) which I would like to manipulate on my web application client. How do I go about doing this?

Or do I need to create in-built instances into the application and set all the drivers myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial answer as it turns out!

Modify it with a jdbc connector like any normal MySQL database. Just remember to add the h2 connection driver to your lib or maven folder.